# Find div closest to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project and I have an array of elements that are displayed one under each other.

When I press an arrow, I want to find the div closest to the bottom and scroll up to the top of that div.

This is what I have when I click the arrow:

```
$(".my-elements").each(function(i){
    var divTopPosition = $(this).offset().top;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    var difference = -Math.abs(scrollTop - divTopPosition);

    if(/* this is the div closest to the bottom */)
    {
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: difference}, 2000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: But what is supposed to be the `div closest to the bottom`??? In DOM order or as displayed in layout or what???

Comment: First iterate over all the .my-elements and check which is the "closest from the bottom". Outside the .each() you do whatever you need. You can't do that "if" before iterate over all items.

Comment: Could you add HTML in the question?

Comment: If you mean the last matched element, use `$(".my-elements").last()`

Answer (score 1):

if you know parent, you can use this selector:

```
$( "<parent>:last-child" )
```

Comment: Well in this case i guess you mean instead to use `$('div:last')`